# Why do the majority of my batters keep splitting no matter what?

Tags: cake, cookies, batter, emulsion

I have been baking for around 3 years now and I have been constantly having a problem with split batters for the past few months all of a sudden. After I add eggs, my cake, cookie, etc. batters slowly begins splitting. For reference, my ingredients are always at room temperature. I scrape the bowl constantly before adding the eggs and after each addition. I slowly add the eggs. I cannot find an answer to my question online, as I always see “cold eggs,” but that is simply not the case.

Comment: Can you give an example of a recipe that’s giving you problems?

Comment: The method as well as the ingredients in the recipe.

Comment: Could there be some new equipment or other change contributing to this?